# How to add users from column 1 to column 2 using codeigniter?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

### How to add users from column 1 to column 2 using codeigniter?

Column 1 has all the usernames and column 2 is the blank lines

---

```
|-----|--------|------------|
|Users|        |Moderators  |
|-----|--------|------------|
|Mark |        |____________|
|JOhn |        |____________|
|Xyz  |        |____________|
|ABC  |->Add   |____________|
|you  |->Remove|____________|
|Me   |->Undo  |____________|
|HIm  |        |____________|
|WE   |        |____________|
|123  |        |____________|
|321  |        |____________|
|-----|--------|------------|

       Save OPtion
```

---

There are two columns, Column 1 has all the users on it and column 2 is for the moderators. If an admin selects one of the user then clicks on add then user must be in the column 2

Since my reputation is low I cannot post images...So I am posting a real time example.  ([**Screenshot**](http://www.flickr.com/photos/95621694@N02/8725527372/in/photostream))

Any tutorial on it please?
Thank you

Comment: @Gautam3164 I know how to display all the users from the database ...I am stuck from there

Comment: You want the `JavaScript` part or `PHP` part or **both**???

Comment: You'll need to learn [Javascript `onclick()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) or [jQuery's `.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and [**Ajax in codeigniter**](http://www.technicalkeeda.com/details/simple-ajax-post-example-with-php-codeIgniter-framework-and-jquery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make left side like

```
<select name="users" multiple>
  <option value="mark">Mark</option>
  <option value="john">John</option>
  <option value="zyx">XYZ</option>
  <option value="abc">ABC</option>
</select>
```

you can use form submit , insert the selected in moderator table and fetch and display the moderator users in page

If you want without page reload
Use java script
show the selected value in moderator col

here is the live soln
http://jsfiddle.net/asvignesh/RMgQq/

Comment: @Ramadal Falco now that U got Click Part sorted out U can handle the rest with ajax... :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume they are colummns not 2 separate tables as you write. Despite the fact that it's weird solution you can update your table.

Move to other column

```
UPDATE `yourtablename` SET MODERATORS=USERS;
UPDATE `yourtablename` SET USERS=NULL;
```

Move back other column

```
UPDATE `yourtablename` SET USERS=MODERATORS;
UPDATE `yourtablename` SET MODERATORS=NULL;
```

but as I wrote it's **weird**. If you have two tables you should use **INSERT INTO** remember that for such queries you should use **transactions**.

Better way is to create something like **ACL(Access Control List)** and to put some **roles** and **resources**

You need three tables for this.

Roles can be

- Administrator
- Moderator
- User
- Supermoderator

  etc.

Resources can be

- Modify article
- View article
- Delete article

Then you can write connections between two tables and users. Also there should be connection between users and roles. You should put table that check if user is administator. For example with structure

```
user_id, role_id
```

also table with assign roles to resources

```
role_id, resource_id
```

Then you can simply check:

```
$user->isAllowed("ModifyArticle");
```

This is the best solution.

If you want to simplify it you can put flags in your user fields to check if user is admin or moderator or you can add some fields to your user table like: "isAdmin", "isModerator" but it is bad design of table. Check also [Zend_ACL](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.acl.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO moderators SET ModUserField='" . $user_field[1] . "', ModUserField2='" . $user_field[0] . "'";

$sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE UserID=" . $user_id;
```

Comment: i think they are asking for HTML / javascript code rather than php mysql stuff.

Comment: Makes a bit more sense ^_^